# Why doesn't Ajax Async File Upload hit Uploaded Complete event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I have used Ajax Async File Upload in UpdatePanel, It shows that file has been uploaded but it doesn't hit `Uploaded Complete Event`.

```
 protected void FileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        HdnFieldHasFileUploaded.Value = "1";
    }
```

why ?

Comment: Where's your upload code?

Comment: @FKutsche that doesn't matter, it should have been hit when uploading completes from browser side